# Apache Superset. ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing OAuth access token: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0, apache-superset

I have a problem. I want to integrate my oauth server to Apache Superset. My Superset configs

```
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager
```

```
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "orion",
        "icon": "fa-google",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": "*****",
            "client_secret": "***************************",
            "client_kwargs": {"scope": "*"},
            "access_token_url": "https://oauth.my.ru/oauth/token",
            "access_token_method": "POST",
            "authorize_url": "https://oauth.my.ru/oauth/authorize",
            "authorize_method": "POST",
        },
    },
]
```

```
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):
        logger.warning("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))
        logger.error("Oauth2 provider: {0}.".format(provider))

        if provider == 'orion':
            # As example, this line request a GET to base_url + '/' + userDetails with Bearer  Authentication,
    # and expects that authorization server checks the token, and response with user details
            me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get('userinfo').data
            logger.warning("user_data: {0}".format(me))
            logger.warning(f"AaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa{me}")
            logger.warning(f"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb{provider}")
            return { 'name' : me['name'], 'email' : me['email'], 'id' : me['user_name'], 'username' : me['user_name'], 'first_name':'', 'last_name':''}
        else:
            logger.warning(f"Это не Орион {provider}, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
            logger.error(
                f"Это не Орион {provider}, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
```

My oauth api

```
@flask_cors.cross_origin()
@app.route('/oauth/token', methods=['POST'])
def access_token() -> Response:
    """
    @api {post} /oauth/token

    @apiHeaderExample {json} Header-Example:
        {
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        }

    @apiSuccessExample
        {
            'scope': '*',
            'expires_in': ...,
            'expires_at': ...,
            'token_type': 'Bearer',
            'access_token': '...',
            'refresh_token': '...'
        }
    """
    return authorization.create_token_response()
```

My oauth server response

```
 {
            'scope': '*',
            'expires_in': ...,
            'expires_at': ...,
            'token_type': 'Bearer',
            'access_token': '...',
            'refresh_token': '...'
        }
```

And I have this problem **2024-02-26 14:22:14,163:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing OAuth access token: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2024-02-26 15:22:13'**
I think, that flask cannot parse my response